# can an array be used with and?

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement

Below I have the following

```
if [[ -n $ip ]] && [[ -n $netmask ]] && [[ -n $gateway ]] && [[ -n $dns ]]; then
```

If all variable are set then return true, else return false

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for brevity -- `[[ -n $ip ]]` is same as `[[ $ip ]]`. Also, you can put all the variables inside one `[[` keyword, the evaluations would happen the same:

```
if [[ $ip && $netmask && $gateway && $dns ]]; then
```

Comment: That's correct. Another (combined) way ist the following: [[ -n "${ip}${netmask}${gateway}${dns}" ]]

Comment: [[ -n $ip ]] not same as [[ $ip ]], because with `ip=''` 1 return `false` and 2 return `true`

Comment: Generally the unset and empty difference is seen setting defaults with, e.g. `${foo+default}`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's correct but I meant in this context they should behave the same and my tests are also justifying that...

Comment: Yes, yes, I understood correctly, you are correct, I was just racking my brain on where it *did* make a difference as a compare/contrast explanation. Good answer.